# Is there a way to do a kind of TryStart for a task in c# TPL (without locking)?

Tags: c#, .net, locking, task-parallel-library, task

So that if the Task has not started yet by another thread, the Task will start.

For example

```
private readonly object syncObj = new object();
private Task<Resource> task;

public Resource GetResource()
{
    lock (syncObj)
    {                
        if (task == null)
            task = Task.Factory.StartNew<Resource>(CreateResource);
    }

    task.Wait();

    return task.Result;
}

private Resource CreateResource()
{
    //do something
}
```

Is there a way to rewrite `GetResource()` without using `lock` at all so it remains thread-safe?

Comment: You could use [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: What framework version are you using? This code isn't necessary in .NET 4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're trying to lazily create some resource. You can do that with [`AsyncLazy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn268899.aspx). Moreover since you're already blocking on the task you can use just a regular `Lazy`:

```
Lazy<Resource> _lazy = new Lazy<Resource>(CreateResource);

public Resource GetResource()
{
    return _lazy.Value;
}
```

But to directly answer your question. If you want to remove the lock and still have `CreateResource` run on a different thread you can do that by using `TaskCompletionSource` and `Interlocked.CompareExchange`:

```
public Resource GetResource()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Resource>();
    var storedTask = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref task, tcs.Task, null);
    if (storedTask != null)
    {
        return storedTask.Result;
    }

    var resource = Task.Factory.StartNew<Resource>(CreateResource).Result;
    tcs.SetResult(resource);
    return resource;
}
```

This only sets `task` to `tcs.Task` if it contains `null` atomically and returns the original value of `task`. That way we can start the `CreateResource` task only for the first time (where `task == null`) and complete the stored `task` with the result.

This becomes much simpler if you make it asynchronous instead of blocking:

```
async Task<Resource> GetResourceAsync()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Resource>();
    var storedTask = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref task, tcs.Task, null);
    if (storedTask != null)
    {
        return await storedTask;
    }

    var resource = await Task.Run(() => CreateResource());
    tcs.SetResult(resource);
    return resource;
}
```

Comment: @ClayVerValen I'm checking for `null`. Are maybe looking at an earlier version of my answer?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I initially compared with `tcs.Task` as I falsely remembered the return value to be the new value and not the original one. I guess this caused some confusion.

Comment: The real confusion is - does the OP use 4.5 or 4.0? The syntax looks like 4.0, Lazy is only available in 4.5+.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I never get users who ask a question and go away. Don't they want an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I would either use [`AsyncLazy<T>`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/15/asynclazy-lt-t-gt.aspx) as @i3arnon said, or expose the `Task<Resource>` instead of synchronously blocking on it:

```
public Task<Resource> GetResourceAsync()
{
     lock (syncObj)
     {                
         if (task == null)
             task = Task.Run(() => CreateResource);
     }

     return task;
}
```

This way, you let the *caller* decide if he wants to synchronously or asynchronously wait for the result.

When thinking about it, I would probably [expose this as a synchronous operation instead](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx), and let the caller decide if this should be executed on a background thread or not:

```
private readonly Lazy<Resource> resource = new Lazy<Resource>(() => CreateResource(), true);
public Resource GetResource()
{
      return resource.Value;
}
```